# Why doesn't the subsection show in the header?

Tags: header-footer

I want my header to show the section name on the left and subsection name on the right. I am using this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textit{\thesection \hspace{0.1cm} \leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\thesubsection \hspace{0.1cm} \rightmark}}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
```

However, in the document, the subsection name doesn't show, only the subsection number. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If seems that `\markboth` and `\markright` are designed to NOT effect the changes until the end of the page (right before the headers are created).  If more than one are on the same page, only the first is done.  One can verify that by printing out `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in various locations.

```
\documentclass[twosisde]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The behaviour is explained in the latex companion

Comment: Warning: Due to the asynchronous page shipout routine this could result in wrong header entries: Section and/or subsection heading can be moved to the next page while `\sectionmark` and `\subsection` (in your code) have already changed `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. So the newe header entries would appear one page to early.

Comment: @esdd how do I fix that issue?

Comment: @MonzurRahman - If it happens, add a \pagebreak before \section.

Comment: @JohnKormylo There's another issue with this solution. It doesn't let me use ```\mathcal``` in the subsection headings. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: \mathcal doesn like \xdef.  You can use `\protect\mathcal` or replace \xdef iwith \gdef.

Answer (score 3):

The mark mechanism is used for the running header entries. A mark command sets three variables: one for the last mark of the previous page, one for the first mark set on the current page and one for the last mark set on the current page. When a page starts the three variables are equal.

`\markright` sets its argument as the "right" mark. `\markboth` sets its first argument as the "left" mark and its second argument as the "right" mark.

`\rightmark` uses the first "right" mark set by `\markright` or the second argument of `\markboth` on a page. `\leftmark` uses the last (bottom) "left" mark set by the first argument of `\markboth`.

In the following example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{} }
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{} }
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

the first "right" mark is the empty right argument of `\markboth` excecuted by `\chaptermark`. Therefore there is no subsection entry in the header of page 1:

[image]

You could define `\rightbotmark` for the last "right" mark:

```latex
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
```

and replace `\rightmark` by `\rightbotmark` to use the last "right" mark of the page:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}% <- added
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightbotmark}}% <- changed
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{} }
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{} }
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

But now there is no subsection entry in the header of page 3, because the empty right argument of `\markboth` is the last "right" mark on this page:

[image]

---

Additional remark:

Do not set `\leftmark` by `\chaptermark` and `\rightmark` by `\sectionmark` without the mark mechanism. Due to the asynchronous page shipout routine this could result in wrong header entries: Section and/or subsection heading can be moved to the next page while `\sectionmark` and `\subsection` have already changed \leftmark and \rightmark. So the new header entries appear one page to early in the following example:

```latex
%% Warning: Do not use this code. It shows only that `\markboth` and `\markright` must be used.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[2-6]
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]