# How does LaTeX (and titlesec, for that matter) chooses which heading goes in the running headers?

Tags: titlesec

If I have several sections in one page, how does LaTeX decide which one goes in the running header? what is the mechanism for this?

Comment: `titlesec` doesn't cater for headers, unless you use  `titleps` and define a page style. What is your problem?

Comment: There is no specific problem. However, sometimes I produce documents which have several headers in one page (say, several sections), and I haven't figured out what is the criteria the software uses to determine which header goes in the running header. Is not the first one, nor the last, and also it doesn't seem to be the determined by the amount of text in the section. I just don't understand why LaTeX chooses one section header or another to place it on the running header. I know can manually tell LaTeX to use a specific one, but I don't understand how it makes the choice or when.

Comment: How the header is determined depends partially on the document class and the package (If any) you are using to manage the headers themselves. So you'll need to make the question a bit more concrete since different document class/header packages might make different choices.

Comment: Usually, \chapter and \section define macros \leftmark and \rightmark which are used by \pagestyle{headings} (\ps@headings).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I understand that. My issue is *when* and *how* that happens when several \section or \chapter commands render said chapters or section sin the same page. Which one does it take? Why that one and no other? It doesn't seem to be determined by which one appears first.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516938/why-doesnt-the-subsection-show-in-the-header

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, that is a good clue.