# How to get \markboth to work from within \tcolorbox and \longtable environments?

Tags: header-footer, environments, longtable, tcolorbox, page-numbering

So I am editing a historical manuscript, and I want the original page numbers of the handwritten manuscript to appear in the running head, both on the left and the right pages. As well, they also need to appear in the text, at the start of each original page (which can be anywhere on the printed page).

I implemented this using a command called `\origpage` which prints the original page number and executes a \markboth command to change the header.

So far so good. Except that sometimes the original page number appears within a table (rendered with `\longtable`) or at the beginning of a box (rendered with `\tcolorbox`). In these cases, the `\markboth` command somehow doesn’t manage to “reach” the running head, apparently because it’s encased in the `\tcolorbox` or `\longtable` environment. The `\markboth` command works when encased in a blank environment, though, so it’s not the environment per se that blocks its effect.

The MWE here shows only the `\tcolorbox` case. If you compile the code, you will see that first ten original pages create the running head correctly, but then the eleventh and twelfth original pages fail, but the thirteenth and fourteenth work again.

Why is this failing?

Can anybody help me figure out a way to get the original page numbers up in the running head even from within a `\tcolorbox` or `\longtable`? Would using `\fancyhdr` help?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX spellcheck = en_EN

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newcommand{\origpage}[1]{%
   {\textsf{\large{[#1.]}}}%
   \markboth{\hfill #1 \hfill}{\hfill #1 \hfill}
}

% +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\origpage{1} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{2} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{3} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{4} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{5} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{6} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{7} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{8} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{9} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{10} \lipsum \lipsum 

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,valign=center,breakable]
\origpage{11} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{12} \lipsum \lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}

\origpage{13} \lipsum \lipsum \origpage{14} \lipsum \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: marks have to be at the top level to be seen by the page breaker.  even a simple `\mbox` is enough to stop that working. however `longtable` should work as long as you do it in a c l or r column, a `p` column can not work as it generates a `\parbox`

Comment: Indeed the custom page numbers I had put inside `longtable` are in `p` columns. I'll have to try the c-l-r approach.

Comment: tcolorbox could probably restore marks similar to multicol, but that something the package will have to do.

Comment: For `longtable`, the c-l-r approach indeed fixes the `\markboth` problem. But I need to set the column widths in the table and using `p` columns is the only way to do that, isn't it?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516938/why-doesnt-the-subsection-show-in-the-header/516974?r=SearchResults&s=7|8.7664#516974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved the problem, and got the output I wanted, with two nasty workarounds. But they will not work for all cases.

With the `\longtable` environment: I just ended the `longtable`, typeset the original page number (so that the resulting `\markboth` is at the top level), and restarted the table. This was not what I wanted as a document designer, but it is not a disaster either.

With the `\tcolorbox`: in my actual code, the `\tcolorbox` is called by an environment (call it `\mybox`). At first I tried to have the `\origpage` command, within the `\tcolorbox`, set a flag that would be preserved and analyzed by the closing braces of the `\mybox` environment. However, the value of this flag was not preserved after the end of `\tcolorbox`. So this approach did not work. (Perhaps there could be a solution with `\gdef`?)

I found another approach that did work. That was to change the original page number to an optional argument of the `\mybox` environment. That allowed the `\mybox` environment to use if statements to issue the `\markboth` command at top level, and also to issue the `\origpage` command displaying the original page number within the `tcolorbox`. This only worked in my case because the `\tcolorboxes` are short and never span a page break, and because the original page number always appears at the beginning of the box. Using `xparse` environment definitions is necessary because the argument has to be used in the closing braces of the environment statement. This is not how I wanted to set up the file and I didn't find it very elegant, but it did get the job done.

Essentially it's like this:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{o}
 {
  \begin{tcolorbox}
  \IfValueT{#1}{{\large{[#1.]}}}
 }
 {
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\markboth{\hfill #1 \hfill}{\hfill #1 \hfill}}%
 }
```